# Calculating Porbabilites in a Bayesian Network

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

I have got the following Network and porbabilites
[image]

And I need to Calculate the probability $P(C=False)$

I triend using the formula for joint porability distributions
$P(X_1,…,X_n)= \prod_{i=1}^{n}P(X_i∣ parents (X_i))$
,and got $P(C=False)=P(C=False|A,B)$.

If I am not wrong, you can infer that $P(C=False|A,B) = 0.75$ from the table of probabilites , but I would like to know what is the general way to solving a problem like this in case not all the probabilities for each case are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to calculate:

$$\begin{align}
P(C=False)&=\sum_{a,b} P(C=False,A=a,B=b)\\
&=\sum_{a,b}P(C=False|A=a,B=b)P(A=a, B=b)\\
&=\sum_{a,b}P(C=False|A=a,B=b)P(A=a)P(B=b)
\end{align}$$

Here, $a, b$ can be $True, False$. Values in the summation can be substituted from the table.